# Wordpress doesn't create the directory for images under wp-content/uploads

Tags: php, wordpress

I am unable to upload pictures using the Wordpress "media" feature in the dashboard.

The path uses a directory of "10" in the path: /wp-content/uploads/2018/10

I logged into myPHPadmin and the "10" directory didn't exist.  I created the "10" directory.

I then used the media feature in the Wordpress dashboard and uploaded an image.  The thumbnail image didn't show at first but when I refresh the screen it appeared.

I looked at the permissions down the entire path of /wp-content/uploads/2018/10
 and they all show 0755.  That permission setting was consistent through the entire directory structure.

I'm not sure why the "10" directory wasn't created automatically by the Wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  I moved my domains and had to update where I stored my uploads.  I had to update the "Store uploads in this folder" box.

Settings -> Media -> Store uploads in this folder